# Metaprogramming: Where does method dispatch look when we call an instance method that is defined inside a class method?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, eigenclass

I'm reading [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) and just want to clear something up about the following *paraphrased* code:

```
class MyClazz
  def self.my_class_method(name)
    define_method(name) {
      # do stuff
    }
  end

  my_class_method :foo
  my_class_method :bar
end

# The code above generates instance methods:

# def foo
#   do stuff
# end

# def bar
#   do stuff
# end
```

**Q1**
My first question regards the two method calls at the end of the file: `my_class_method :foo` and `my_class_method :bar`. Am I right in thinking that they are both invoked automatically when a MyClazz object is instantiated?

**Q2** When Ruby generates these methods (`def foo` and `def bar`), it will put them in *MyClazz's* eigenclass, even though they are instance methods. So does this mean that Ruby looks to the eigenclass for both class and instance methods when needed?

I just want to clear that up before I move too far into the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer 1:** *(short)* They are invoked when ruby instantiate `MyClass` instance (of type `Class`).

*(long)* When Ruby interpreter sees a class definition (`class MyClazz`) it instantiate an instance of this class and evaluate all the code inside class definition.

In your case `MyClazz` is a constant that holds a refference to the object of class `Class`. And when Ruby initialize it, it execute code inside class definition - defines singleton method `my_class_method` of this `Class` instance and executes method `my_class_method` twice in the context of this `Class` instance.

**Answer 2:** *(short)* `Module#define_method` private method adds method to the method table of `Class` instance (method table holds instance methods of the class). It does not affect eigenclass of istance object/class object.

*(long)* When you call instance method on the object, Ruby first looks this method in the eigenclass of this object, then in the superclass of eigenclass (it will be a `Class` object of the object's class). But it will not look in the eigenclass of `MyClazz`
object.

**Example:**

```
obj = MyClazz.new
obj.foo # => ok
```

`obj.foo` will look for `foo` method definition in eigenclass of `obj` object, then will look for instance methods of `MyClass` (instance of class `Class`), then in the superclass of `MyClass` object (in your case this is `Object` class) etc.

```
obj = MyClass.new
MyClass.my_class_method :baz
obj.baz # => ok
```

`MyClass.my_class_method` will look for `my_class_method` method definition in the eigenclass of `MyClass` object (sidenote: eigenclass of a class sometimes is
 called a *metaclass*) and it will find it here and will add `baz` instance method to the class `MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

A1: Yes these methods are created upon instantiation.

A2: Russ Olsen does a great job of explaining this in his book Eloquent Ruby. The eigenclass (or singleton class) "sits between every object and its regular class". As such, when Ruby doesn't find the method it's looking for in the instance methods, it will begin traveling up the inheritance tree. The next stop is the eigenclass and from there the class itself.

Olsen also gives an interesting discussion about how all Class methods are actually singleton methods between the new class and the Class object.

Comment: thanks for the tip, and I'll read Russ Olsen's book too, looks good